# Express routes in ViteJS returns 'index.html' when accessed in production

Tags: express, svelte, vite

I'm creating a website using Vitejs and Svelte template for the first time. I've wanted to use a simple server side verification using express, but I'm struggling to make it work in production.

In my local environment, when I post to my routes, everything works as expected, no problem.
However, when my app is built, it seems that my express server is not running and so are my routes.

**When I call my 'route', it just returns me a 200 status and the content of 'index.html'.** It does this only when my app is built.

In my `vite.Config.js` I initiate my server...

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
      css: (css) => {
        css.write("public/bundle.css");
      },
    }),
  ],
});

async function initServer() {
  const app = express();

  app.post("/access", async (req, res) => {
    // my route
  });

  app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`App listening at ${port}`) });
}

initServer();
```

... which is called in code with `await axios.post('/validate-email', { options });`

I've already tackled the route call in my `axios.post` which differ between development and production, but my routes do not exist.

Is there an "easy" way to resolve this, or should I use SSR or a backend integration like `vite-express` (and are they even a solution ?) ?

> What I tried/expect

I tried using Vitejs `Middleware`, without success (I'm not even sur if I used it correctly),
I tried creating a server file and passing it to my `Vite.Config.js` but it's the same.

My server is running correctly on my local environment but not in my production environment, when built.

EDIT

Because my routes were just using axios to post to APIs, I tried to not use it, and use proxies in my `vite.config.js` , like this...

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/mail-check": {
        target: "https://my-api.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.MV_API_KEY}`,
        },
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/mail-check/, ""),
        secure: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

... but in the end I have the exact same problem as before.
**When I call my 'route', it just returns me a 200 status and the content of 'index.html'**

At this point I don't really know how to do it, event tough it seems simple. I tried `vite-express` without much success either.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing building a react app in vite. The issue was that vite couldn't bundle my env when building for some reason. I had to downgrade vite to 4.2 before it could work. The current ver was 4.4. Check if this works for you. The other solution is to hardcode the env var although this is obviously not advisable.